# insert value from two databases in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, psql, dblink

Can I perform a

```
select dblink_exec ('merg',E'insert into table1(col1,col2) select * from dblink(\'mc\',\'select distinct col1, col2 from table2\') as t(col1 bigint, col2 text)');
```

to be able to insert a select from a different database on the same server ?

I also tried to execute the second part into a view and then select from the view but did not work

Comment: You can use a FDW: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Fdw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is to connect to one of the databases then execute

```
CREATE EXTENSION dblink
```

then just use:

```
select dblink_exec('dbname=table1', ....)
```